# What are the Symmetric Algorithm, Scheme, and KDF parameters used for in TPM2 CreatePrimary?

Tags: tpm

When interfacing with a TPM 2.0 device, you can request that it calculate the TPM's Endorsement Keys as "Primary" Objects using `CreatePrimary`. As I understand it, the TPM's singular Endorsement Primary Seed (EPS) can be used to generate an Endorsement Key using a specific set of parameters (for example, you can request an RSA 2048 key or maybe an ECC Nist P256 key, if the TPM supports that). As long as you make the same request to `CreatePrimary` and the EPS remains the same, then the TPM will deterministically derive the same key pair. However it's also possible to generate many Endorsement Keys with different parameters, per [Part 1, section 14.2](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TCG_TPM2_r1p59_Part1_Architecture_pub.pdf).

I'm attempting to understand the various fields in the arguments to `CreatePrimary` and match them to the relevant portions of the TPM 2.0 specification documents.

In [Part 1](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TCG_TPM2_r1p59_Part1_Architecture_pub.pdf), 11.14.10 Key Derivation Function says that the KDF used to map from the EPS to the derived key is SP800-108. The KDF requires a hash function for the HMAC it internally uses. Passed to the KDF are two parameters "Label" and "Context" which are not defined in this section.

In [Part 1, section 14.1](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TCG_TPM2_r1p59_Part1_Architecture_pub.pdf) it says "After the TPM
generates a Primary Object, it uses the parameters of that object and the Primary Seed to generate a symmetric key to encrypt the sensitive portion of the object (that is, the private data and authorizations)". I don't understand this statement fully. I understand that the TPM has only limited amounts of working memory so objects that are not immediately needed can be encrypted and sent to the caller to hold on to until they are needed. The caller must load them back into memory to use them. The `CreatePrimaryLoaded` API will directly load the derived key pair into memory for immediate use. Is the implication that the symmetric algorithm parameters of `CreatePrimary` are influencing the encryption wrapper that the TPM is using to protect the unloaded key data? Why would the TPM firmware author not just unilaterally pick this as an implementation detail, since the unloaded keypair is meant to be opaque to the caller?

Later on, in [Part 1, section 23.7](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TCG_TPM2_r1p59_Part1_Architecture_pub.pdf) it says "The sensitive area of a Primary
Object is not returned in the TPM2_CreatePrimary() or TPM2_CreateLoaded() response. The Primary Object will need to be regenerated each time it is needed, or it can be made persistent in NV memory on the TPM". So then what is the Symmetric Algorithm parameter used for?

[Part 1, Section 27.2.6](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TCG_TPM2_r1p59_Part1_Architecture_pub.pdf) is where I'd expect the document to explain some of these details, but instead it just makes a vague statement that the exact contents of the parameter field depends on the type of key being derived. There's no reference to a table to look up the parameters for each key type, as I would have expected.

[Part 3, Section 24.1](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TCG_TPM2_r1p59_Part3_Commands_pub.pdf) doesn't really shed much more light on the situation.